# Why can I remove an item from the menu but cannot hide it?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

Following code remove an item from the BottonNavigationView. It works correctly.

```
@Override
protected void hideUselessBottomBarButtons(Menu menu) {
    BottomNavigationView theMenuOfTheCujons = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    theMenuOfTheCujons.getMenu().removeItem(0);
}
```

But if I change **removeItem(0)** to **setVisible(false)** it does not works, button is still there.

```
protected void showBottomMenuItems() {
    Menu bottomMenu = mBottomNavigationView.getMenu();

    if (bottomMenu.size() == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mMenuItemList.size(); i++) {




            if (bottomMenu.size() < mBottomNavigationView.getMaxItemCount()) {
                if (getItemTitle(i) != 0) {


                    if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                        (bottomMenu.add(Menu.NONE, getItemId(i), i, getItemTitle(i)).setIcon(getItemIcon(i))).setVisible(false);
                        Badger.sett(bottomMenu.getItem(i), mCircleFactory).setCount(0);
                    }else {
                        (bottomMenu.add(Menu.NONE, getItemId(i), i, getItemTitle(i)).setIcon(getItemIcon(i))).setVisible(true);
                        Badger.sett(bottomMenu.getItem(i), mCircleFactory).setCount(0);
                    }

                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();


                }

                updateBadgeCounters(i, bottomMenu);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    BottomNavigationViewUtils.disableShiftMode(mBottomNavigationView);
}
```

bottom_navigation layout is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:background="@color/color_button_bar"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/navigation_item_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/navigation_item_selector"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"/>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

you should call:  `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();` if you are using `AppCompatActivity` or `invalidateOptionMenu()` if your are using `Activity`.

```
 theMenuOfTheCujons.getMenu().getItem(0).setVisible(false);
 supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Comment: I am using `AppCompatActivity` so I have added `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();` but... no results.

Comment: Activity is really big, any part in particular?

Comment: the part that you are creating the menu and using it.

Comment: I have added the parte where the items are added to menu. As you can see I have added the `setVisible(true)`and `setVisible(false)`in needed parts. Still does not work.